# How to place multiple lines of text in one single table cell in vimwiki?

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

I want to have multiple lines of text appear in one cell (one row and one column).

In Vimwiki it looks adequate.  However, when I convert Vimwiki to HTML, each sentence gets its own row.  So I know I am not getting it right, but I have not yet been able to figure out what I am missing.

## MWE

This vimwiki text

```
= Test =

Regular Text

    Blockquote

| Special Table               |
|-----------------------------|
| First Sentence              |
| Second Sentence, same cell. |
| Third Sentence, same cell.  |
|                             |
|                             |  

Regular text
```

produces this HTML:

```
<p>
Regular Text
</p>
<blockquote>
Blockquote
</blockquote>

<table>
<tr>
<th>
Special Table
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
First Sentence
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Second Sentence, same cell.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Third Sentence, same cell.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>
Regular text
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want HTML to look like this:

```
<p>
Regular Text
</p>
<blockquote>
Blockquote
</blockquote>

<table>
<tr>
<th>
Special Table
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
First Sentence<br>
Second Sentence, same cell.<br>
Third Sentence, same cell.<br>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>
Regular text
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have read the help pages:

```
If you set > in a cell, the cell spans the left column.
If you set \/ in a cell, the cell spans the above row
```

I have not been able to use those details to produce the output I want.

**How do I tell Vimwiki to put all of those lines of text into one single table cell?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the functionality I wanted to vimwiki and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/pull/331) to get it incorporated into the main body of code.

In the process of doing this, I realized I can accomplish my larger goal using `blockquote` and CSS that vimwiki also currently provides.

Comment: Thanks! I tried lots of things, but `blockquote` is really what I was looking for as well!

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain how you can achieve this behaviour with `blockquote`? I don't know much about HTML or CSS. I know I can use other HTML tags (i.e. `<b>bold text<\b>`) but haven't managed to get `<blockquote>text<\blockquote>` to work in Vimwiki.

Answer (score 2):

The vimwiki syntax does not support what you want.

When you use `>` or `\/` you are giving the left/above column more space but the text has to be written there and may not span multiple lines.

[You could ask for this feature on GitHub](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues).